# SOAP. JAX-WS. Authorization

Tags: java, soap, authorization, testng, jax-ws

1. So, i have parsed WSDL by -wsimport to my project.
2. Then, i initialize them
3. Did some request

soapServicePortType = Interface, where is methods of WSDL.
getHouseCall = GETmethod of info

[image: screen]

4. But i should authorizate
5. As i see in stacktrace, message building by HttpTransportPipe class. In this class i found method "addBasicAuth", when i can insert Login and pass.

So, i have 2 questions:

1. How to make my request use "addBasicAuth" method when it building request
2. How to add one header (coockie) to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it so:

```
((BindingProvider) /*Insert InterfaceClass of port WSDL*/).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "login");
((BindingProvider) /*Insert InterfaceClass of port WSDL*/).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "password");
```

And no need to sending coockies